# What am I doing wrong when I am attempting to update MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Updating MongoDB: `db.inspections.updateOne( { id: "20032-2020-ACME", business_name: "ACME Explosives" }, { $set: { "business_name.$": "New ACME Flowers" } })`

I have tried several of the versions of the above, but I only get this back: `acknowledged: true, insertedId: null, matchedCount: 0, modifiedCount: 0, upsertedCount: 0 }`
It does not seem to be updating, even though I am in the correct Database and Collection. If I try to find it nothing happens.

Comment: `matchedCount: 0`. Your filter criteria don't match any document in the collection. Have you checked whether the document exists with MongoDB Compass?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `_id` (which is a required field for documents in MongoDB) rather than `id`?

Comment: What does `db.inspections.findOne({id: "20032-2020-ACME"})` show?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it show this. acknowledged: true, insertedId: null, matchedCount: 0, modifiedCount: 0, upsertedCount: 0 }

Comment: Are you using `mongosh` or some other MongoDB client?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Mongosh. I didn't know there was another option. Well, I use it could be for window, but I am on a mac.

Comment: @user20042973 It did not work. It gave me the same output. Thanks

Comment: `db.inspections.findOne` will return `null` if no document is found.  Please try again the command from my previous comment.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I got it done. I believe the database was down at school. Cause I was able to do that assignment just find the way you said after I inserted the info again. Thanks for your help